# Laravel, can global/route middleware be disabled programatically?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to disable one or more 'pieces' of middleware (registered globally or on route) based on the request headers.

I'm using Postman to test my API but coming across the issue with CSRF protection as well as auth etc.

So ideally (probably in a Service Provider?) I'd check if the Postman Token was set in the request, along with the environment etc and then disabled certain middleware from being run.

Has anyone done anything like this before, can it be done etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Just comment the middleware you don't need out while testing. I don't think the time and effort needed to do this is worth it given that it's just for debugging. (You need to modify each individual middleware or add a middleware that "fixes" the request if using postman. too much trouble imo)

Comment: Agreed it might be initially time consuming, ideally I'd turn it into a little package that I can add to a few API based projects it would allow colleagues to test shared Postman collections without having to adjust the code base and not accidentally commit the commenting out of middleware (unlikely but you never know!).

Comment: There's no silver bullet for this as far as I can see, you can create a new middleware group for postman requests and change your `RouteServiceProvider::map()` function to register the web routes to that group if the header is set, but that won't affect middleware on individual routes, those  are statically declared in the kernel so you can't easily swap them out, you may need to work out a different solution for those.

Comment: Ok yeah I figured it might not be something clean :(

Thanks for your input though, gives me something to look at. It also makes me realise how little I know about some of the core booting of Laravel whilst trawling through all the booting processes etc. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In the VerifyCsrfToken.php file, there is a an except array that you can populate with your routes, which don't need csrf protected. For example,

```
 protected $except = [
    'api/*',
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have seen this previously but this doesn't allow me to programatically disable based on specific conditions of the request and/or disable multiple middleware.